# Vertical bar between {}

Tags: equations

How could the vertical bar in the following equation be of the same height as the {}?

```
SU(4) = \left \{\begin{pmatrix}
u_{11} & u_{12} & u_{13} & u_{14} \\ 
u_{21} & u_{22} & u_{23} & u_{24} \\ 
u_{31} & u_{32} & u_{33} & u_{34} \\ 
u_{41} & u_{42} & u_{43} & u_{44}
\end{pmatrix}, \ \textup{where} \ u_{\mu \nu} \in \mathbb{C} \ \mid \ u^{\dagger} u = 1, \ \textup{det} u = 1 \right \}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\middle|`. I fixed some notation, but you're free to use yours; on the other hand, I think it's at least misleading.

Note that `\det` is predefined.

I also add how I'd write it, after having stipulated that `M_4(\mathbb{C})` denotes the space of four times four complex matrices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator{\SU}{SU}

\begin{document}

\[
\SU(4) = \left \{ u=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  u_{11} & u_{12} & u_{13} & u_{14} \\
  u_{21} & u_{22} & u_{23} & u_{24} \\
  u_{31} & u_{32} & u_{33} & u_{34} \\
  u_{41} & u_{42} & u_{43} & u_{44}
\end{pmatrix}
  \;\middle|\;
u_{\mu \nu} \in \mathbb{C}, u^{\dagger} u = 1, \det u = 1 \right \}
\]

\[
\SU(4)=\{\, u\in M_4(\mathbb{C}) \mid u^{\dagger}u=1, \det u=1 \,\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\middle` seems to be an e-tex thing, that's why I didn't know it. Nice!

Comment: @PietvanOostrum LaTeX has been e-TeX based for several years.

Answer (score 4):

You can either specify the size of the bar, like `\Biggm|`, but there is a limit on the size that you can get this way.

Or you can use two `\left` `\right` pairs to get the bar of the same size as the braces, but then you must artificially make the right hand part as tall as the left hand part by putting a `\vphantom` with the matrix in it. By the way, I think you shouldn't put your own spaces around the `|`. And there should be a space between `det` and `u`, which I have done below.

Here are both solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mymatrix}{\begin{pmatrix}
u_{11} & u_{12} & u_{13} & u_{14} \\ 
u_{21} & u_{22} & u_{23} & u_{24} \\ 
u_{31} & u_{32} & u_{33} & u_{34} \\ 
u_{41} & u_{42} & u_{43} & u_{44}
\end{pmatrix}}

\[
SU(4) = \left \{\mymatrix, \ \textup{where} \ u_{\mu \nu} \in \mathbb{C} \ \Biggm| \ u^{\dagger} u = 1, \ \det u = 1 \right \}
\]

\[
SU(4) = \left \{\mymatrix, \ \textup{where} \ u_{\mu \nu} \in \mathbb{C} \ \right|
\left. \vphantom{\mymatrix} \ u^{\dagger} u = 1, \ \det u = 1 \right \}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You may have a simpler syntax using the `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` command, from  `mathtools`. Adapting a code from mathtools documentation, I define a `\set` command, with two arguments in one, separated by a semi-colon. It defines a starred version of the command which adapts the size of the delimiters to the size of its contents. In addition I define a `medium-sized` (~ 80 % of `ddisplaystyle`) `pmatrix` environment using `nccmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}%

\newenvironment{medpmatrix}{\medsize\begin{pmatrix}}{\end{pmatrix}\endmedsize}

 \DeclareMathOperator{\SU}{SU}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]\{\}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{\nonscript\,#1\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\allowbreak #2\nonscript\,}}

\begin{document}

\[
\SU(4) = \set*{ u=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  u_{11} & u_{12} & u_{13} & u_{14} \\
  u_{21} & u_{22} & u_{23} & u_{24} \\
  u_{31} & u_{32} & u_{33} & u_{34} \\
  u_{41} & u_{42} & u_{43} & u_{44}
\end{pmatrix} ; u_{\mu \nu} \in \mathbb{C}, u^{\dagger} u = 1, \det u = 1 }
\]

\[
\SU(4) = \set*{ u=
  \begin{medpmatrix}
  u_{11} & u_{12} & u_{13} & u_{14} \\
  u_{21} & u_{22} & u_{23} & u_{24} \\
  u_{31} & u_{32} & u_{33} & u_{34} \\
  u_{41} & u_{42} & u_{43} & u_{44}
\end{medpmatrix} ; u_{\mu \nu} \in \mathbb{C}, u^{\dagger} u = 1, \det u = 1 }
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]